# Убрать border-bottom с последнего списка

Tags: css

Всем привет!
Применил я к `li` спискам "`border-bottom`". Но есть одна проблема, как мне убрать эту обводку с последнего списка. Самая проблема в том, что класс нельзя ставить. Это на `CMS`. То есть, пункты меню `cms` генерирует.. Помогите!

Answer (score 4):

[last-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-child)

> Псевдокласс `:last-child` задает стилевое оформление последнего элемента своего родителя

Comment: IE 7 не поддерживает :(

Comment: с помощью CSS для IE7 никак

Answer (score 1):

а ещё можно **не делать два действия** (т.е. сначала поставить бордер всем элементам а потом у последнего убрать)...

а **сделать одно** (поставить бордер внизу всем кроме последнего):

```
li:not(:last-child){
 border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

или сделать его вверху всем кроме первого:

```
li:not(:first-child){
 border-top:1px solid red;
}
```

*ну и разумеется для IE7 сделать это при помощи чисто CSS (без дополнительного класса) невозможно

Answer (score 0):

Если LI выводятся вертикально, то лучше задать им **border-top** вместо **border-bottom**, а для исключения использовать `li:first-child{border-top: none;}`

Comment: Смысл? Тоже самое что и с border-bottom. Я же говорю, атрибут "first-child" IE 7 не поддерживает. Есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: добавить margin-top: 1px; и у родительского элемента сделать background: black ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/GGvvd/

Comment: @bifot, не работает :last-child, :first-child - без проблем